# Junction box nipple hickey

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, junction-box

So, I've tried to be resourceful and search everywhere but I can't seem to find a solution.

By what I've gathered, my problem might be a "nipple hickey" located in the center of junction box (side note: do NOT Google "nipple hickey" for a solution, at least to this problem).

The center nipple has what looks to be a slot for a flathead screwdriver but it is hollow behind the slot and no way it will turn.

[image]

[image]There looks to be a metal surround possibly holding the nipple in place but I've tried pulling and turning and nothing moves. The surround has notches that don’t line up across from one another so it's nearly impossible to get a good grip to turn it. I can't get a flathead behind it enough to try yanking on it either. Is the solution as simple as this?

I'm trying to remove the box entirely to put in recessed wafer lights; even though the lights are thin, box is still in the way to install.

Is this thing a nipple? A hickey? A *nickey*? If it is or even if it isn't, how do I remove it to take out the box.

Comment: looks like the box is nailed in. Are you referring to a "knockout" hole? It also seems someone applied tightening tourque to part in question; you can see the deformation on the top-left and bottom-right of the slot, which leads me to think it _was_ screwed into place but has since rusted shut.

Comment: Take all the fun out of a search.

Comment: Why do you have to remove it in order to remove the box? It's built in to the box and does not help hold the box in place.

Comment: Back up your camera s little and get the entire box in the picture.

Comment: That is a "hickey stud".  Onto it goes a hickey, which in turn secures a light fixture's nipple.  The hickey is the fitting that joins the nipple to the stud.   The slot is not for a screwdriver.  Now that you've had your chandelier lecture, and your life is better for it, you can just as quickly forget about it and do what @A.I.Breveleri says: a clear picture of the whole box will help us figure out what in fact is preventing you from removing it.

Comment: So now everybody search "hickey stud."

Comment: In electrical terms there are 2 types of hickey’s one is a conduit bender, the other is a threaded mount used in a fixture. I agree don’t try searching for these terms or you might be shocked , I jokingly told an apprentice to describe the 3 types of hickey’s his internet search was flagged as inappropriate use so know there are 2 electrical terms and the other can have surprise pics on line.